# What protocol does ADO.NET uses to communicate with the with database server?

Tags: ado.net, odbc, database-connection, ado

I am trying to understand how does ADO.NET communicate with the database server. From what I know this far, it use either the ODBC and OLE DB APIs to accessing the database.

How does it establish the communication with the database? Does it use an `HttpClient` to create an HTTP request to bridge the communication? Or, does it use other protocols or methods to bridge the communication with the database?